# How can I disable the quicksearch in “Save as...” dialogue?

Tags: filemanager, cinnamon, nemo

In the “Save as...” dialogue the quicksearch function captures keyboard entries if I want to rename the file although the target file name is marked:

[image]

This is annoying. Although I know that I’m getting in that trap again and again.

Does anybody know how to deactivate this quicksearch function?
The same function is used in the Nemo explorer.

I’m using Cinnamon 3.2.7 and Nemo 3.2.2.